# how to install the laravel 8 project?

Tags: laravel-8

```
C:\Users\dell\Desktop>composer create-project laravel/laravel:^8.0 laravel
Creating a "laravel/laravel:8.0" project at "./laravel"
Cannot use laravel/laravel's latest version v8.0.0 as it requires php ^7.3 which is not satisfied by your platform.

In CreateProjectCommand.php line 421:

  Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 8.0 in a version installable using your PHP version, PHP extens
  ions and Composer version.


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--ask] [--] [<package> [<directory> [<version>]]]
```

composer create-project laravel/laravel:^8.0 laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `--ignore-platform-reqs` to ignore the PHP version validation.